# How to provide Social login using spring social In jHipster sample app

Tags: jhipster

How to provide Social login using spring social with normal login In jHipster sample app.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you ever done anything with Social login? Take a look at Spring Social, which should help you go in the right direction.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/